# Groovy Closure after method call

Tags: groovy, closures

A have studied closures in Groovy for some hours, but haven't find explanation how this this creation of file structures works. For me it looks just like some closures after method call. I don't see nesting inside first method called on tree object arguments or chaning of returns.

```
def tree = new FileTreeBuilder()
 tree.dir('src') {
    dir('main') {
       dir('groovy') {
          file('Foo.groovy', 'println "Hello"')
       }
    }
```

Comment: Are you asking how `FileTreeBuilder` is implemented?  If so: take a look at the `methodMissing` implementation in the `FileTreeBuilder` source; I think it will be helpful to understanding this builder.  If you are asking something else, can you clarify what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of possible ways to pass a `Closure` as the last method's argument in Groovy.

e.g. this idiomatic call:

```
       dir('groovy') {
          //...
       }
```

can also be rewritten as (with brackets all around):

```
       dir('groovy', {
          //...
       } )
```

or as (with no brackets at all):

```
       dir 'groovy', {
          //...
       }
```

They are all interchageable and can be used depending on the context.

Comment: thank you, I was not able to google this explanation.

Answer (score 2):

An explanation of the variations for how closures can be passed to methods as parameters can be found [Passing Closures To Methods](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-passing-closures-to.html) and is summarized as follows:

> Closures are blocks of code we can assign to variables and pass around like objects. We can use closures as method arguments, but we must make sure we use the correct syntax. Groovy has some variations we can use to pass a closure into a method. If for example the closure is the last argument for a method we can put the closure outside the argument list.

Your question is asking how a closure can appear outside of the method parenthesis and still work as expected. One variation of passing closures to methods as parameters is if the closure is the last parameter in the method call. In that case, the closure can be outside of the parenthesis (argument list):

```
work('Groovy') {
    assert it == 'Groovy'
}  // Last argument is closure and can be outside parenthesis.
```

So in your example:

```
def tree = new FileTreeBuilder()
 tree.dir('src') {
    dir('main') {
       dir('groovy') {
          file('Foo.groovy', 'println "Hello"')
       }
    }
```

The call to `tree.dir('src'){...}` with a closure following is exactly this case. The closure is treated as the value for the last argument to the method call `tree.dir()` and matches the method signature: `File dir(String name, Closure cl)`